# Zybooks Python Challenge activity 3.5.1

Tags: python

Dictionary room_guest_pairs contains two key-value pairs, each representing a hotel room number and the guest's name. Read a room number from input. Then, output the corresponding guest's name from room_guest_pairs. Finally, delete that pair from room_guest_pairs.

```
room_guest_pairs = {339: 'Sue', 238: 'Eli'}

'Your code here'

print('Remaining pairs:')
print(room_guest_pairs)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
name = room_guest_pairs[int(input())]
print(name)
room_guest_pairs.pop(int(input()))
```

but it only outputs the name, not the other remaining pairs

```
1: Compare output
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Input
238
Your output
Eli
Remaining pairs:
{339: 'Sue', 238: 'Eli'}
Expected output
Eli
Remaining pairs:
{339: 'Sue'}
```

Comment: Did you keep the `print(room_guest_pairs)` from the first code snippet?

Comment: Yes this is what im trying but it won't get rid of the input pair thats currently in the dict.

Comment: Works for me, when I enter the same number twice. (You could ask for the number only once and save the number in a variable and use that. `room = int(input())` and then use `number` instead of `int(input())` in the other places.) And you print the remaining rooms at the end of the program, right? Cause it gets executed line by line from top to bottom, and if you print the rooms before `pop`ing, you are printing the wrong result. It would be easier to help you if you pasted only one code block that has your complete program.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122), particularly the guidance to ask about a specific problem with your existing code -- _instead of_ asking about the challenge or question you were trying to solve when you encountered that problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here, and it's not clear what exactly you need help with. Maybe you want to ask, "How can I save a number read from input?", but you already know how to use variables, so I don't think that's it. If you want more tips, check out [ask].

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to bring out a value in the dictionary (`room_guest_pairs`), you should assign a new variable that can input numbers.
2. Then print output.
3. You should delete one pair in the dictionary, so use `del dictionary[name]`. Put the new variable you just assigned.

Try this code.

```py
room_guest_pairs = {339: 'Sue', 238: 'Eli'}
name = int(input('put guest\'s room number:'))
print(room_guest_pairs[name])
del room_guest_pairs[name]
print('Remaining pairs:')
print(room_guest_pairs)
```